# Kedro 0.16.3 and kedro[spark.SparkDataSet] pip libraries cannot be installed together on databricks cluster

Tags: azure-databricks, kedro

Till last week both kedro and kedro[spark.SparkDataSet] pip libraries were installed on the cluster. But since last 3-4 days they wont be installed together on the cluster. It shows that its a duplicate library but my code also fails as sparkdataset is not found by it. If I install only kedro I get the error as shown in the below screenshot [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiLKm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To install kedro follow this [installation prerequisites](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/get_started/prerequisites.html#installation-prerequisites)

[Install Kedro](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/get_started/install.html#install-kedro)

To install Kedro from the Python Package Index (PyPI) simply run:

```
pip install kedro
```

Sample code -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StringType,
                               IntegerType, StructType)

from kedro.extras.datasets.spark import SparkDataSet

schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)])

data = [('Alex', 31), ('Bob', 12), ('Clarke', 65), ('Dave', 29)]

spark_df = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().createDataFrame(data, schema)

data_set = SparkDataSet(filepath="test_data")
data_set.save(spark_df)
reloaded = data_set.load()

reloaded.take(4)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks after doing this im getting this error - DataSetError: 
No module named 'fsspec.asyn'.
Failed to instantiate DataSet . Please note i have added fsspec to the cluster and pip installed it on the notebook

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install both `pip install kedro["spark.SparkDataSet"]==0.16.3` is a superset of `pip install kedro==0.16.3`

Comment: I get the error as shown in the edited post. This was the reason why I had both in the first place.

Comment: Looking at your response to the other answer here I think you may have a conflicting library installed on the Databricks cluster? Is there anything installed that would conflict with the version of `fsspec` required by this version of kedro?